# PowerShell Add-Content with multiple variables to columns

Tags: powershell, csv

Using `Add-Content` to input multiple variables to a csv file will write each variable to the csv in a new row, such as the following:

**Code**

```
$name, $dateTime, $task | Add-Content $csv  -Force
```

**Results**

```
$name
$dateTime
$task
```

I would like to loop the above code with new variable values each time but would prefer the variables to input to new columns for results such as the following:

```
$name $dateTime $task
$name $dateTime $task
$name $dateTime $task
```

How can I modify my code to input each of the 3 variables into a new column, then on the next pass, input the 3 new values on the next row across columns 1,2 and 3 like the above example?

Thanks

Comment: Where are the values coming _from_? How are you assigning the variables `$name` etc?

Comment: Add-Content works with strings, `"$name, $dateTime, $task" | Add-Content` to make your variables into a string line of the right kind for your CSV.

Comment: (Or use `Export-Csv -Append` but you'll need to make a PSCustomObject of the right shape, which will only work if the CSV format is exactly what PowerShell wants)

Comment: this sounds like an XY problem. You are trying to make a CSV? If you have proper objects you could just look into `Export-CSV`. For now you could just `"$name $dateTime $task" | Add-Content $csv  -Force`

Comment: @Matt Thanks, that does write it across but only in a single cell. I would like each of the 3 variables to log into A1, B1, C1.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I will play with `Export-CSV -Append` - thanks

Comment: @gms0ulman they are named earlier in the script, they are strings. I am happy to walk you through it but i'm curious why that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a suggestion from @TessellatingHeckler, I used `Export-CSV -Append` and created a `pscustomobject` like so:

```
$logData = @(
 [pscustomobject]@{
  Name = $name
   DateTime = $dateTime
    Task = $task
}
)
$logData | Export-Csv $csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

By doing so I achieved two desirable effects; column headers and each variable is written to it's own cell per each iteration of the loop.

**Results**

```
Name  DateTime  Task
$name $dateTime $task
$name $dateTime $task
```

Thanks, everyone.